# What is the use of SQL Server Integration Services Server in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2016

In SQL Server there is a separate Server we install for SSIS but when we deploy a project it goes to SQL Server Database engine (Integration Services Catalogs, SSISDB).

[image: Object Explorer connected to both SQL Server & Integration Services]

What is the use of this Integration Services here? I'm new to this and couldn't find any article talking about this Integration Services login.

Comment: You don't need it. It exists for *older* package types. In fact, the latest versions of SSMS can't even connect to it

Answer (score -1):

In SSIS, when you choose **package deployment** model and create a deployment utility ie **Deployment manifest**, at that time we have option of deploy it on integration services.

In SQL 2012+ By default we use project deployment which creates our `.dtsx` in SSISDB folder under Integration  Service Catalog.

As said in comments, it is just for compatibility purpose now.

Here is a short demonstration of how to use it :

[image: image1]

then click next :

[image: image2]

Now you will be able to see the package inside MSDB folder.
From here you can run the package as well as maintain it.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. In fact, the packages will appear in "Integration Services Catalogs", *not* the separate SSIS server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It will appear in Integration Services Catalogs if you choose 'project deployment' and not 'package deployment'. Prior to 2012, This was the way to go for deploying.

Comment: *Was*. 2012 is the earliest supported version. There is no reason to use project deployment. This still doesn't answer the question - "What is the use ?": None, it's only there for compatibility reasons

Comment: It's not my view. That's what the [documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/integration-services-service-ssis-service)